# Unable to call Context Provider in react

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing aws cognito service in my react app.

I created a login page and applied the authentication method, it was working fine.
Now for state management, I wanted context.provider that will pass the authentication to all other pages.

When I am trying to useContext in my login page then it is giving error: `failed to login Error: Username and Pool information are required.`

My login.js page looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { AccountContext } from './Account';

const LoginPage = props => {
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

const { authenticate } = useContext(AccountContext);

const onSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  authenticate(username, password)
  .then(data => {
    console.log('logged in', data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error is here');
    console.error('failed to login', err);
  });
};
```

It seems like it is not going inside `authenticate` function.

Can you please suggest me where am I going wrong?

My account.js(context provider) file:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
import Pool from '../../UserPool';

const AccountContext = createContext();

const Account = props => {
  const authenticate = async (username, password) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const user = new CognitoUser({ username, Pool });
    const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({ username, password });

    user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
     onSuccess: data => {
      console.log('onSuccess: ', data);
      resolve(data);
      // setIsLoggedIn(true);
    },
    onFailure: err => {
      console.error('onFailure: ', err);
      reject(err);
    }
  });
});
};
 return (
  <AccountContext.Provider value={{ authenticate }}>
    {props.children}
  </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { Account, AccountContext };
```

Comment: The error is coming from Cognito and not React. You're supposed to setup the configuration initially before calling cognito methods.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I solved it now :)